# How to make the browser allow notification disappear while running automate test using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I don't want Allow Notifications pop up appear while I'm running automate script and I try to block it by manual (block it in browser setting). Browser is Firefox.

```
Test
[Tags]    Regression
Open Excel    ${Data.${ENV_DATA}}
@{getCustInfor}=    Get Sheet Values    CardNo
@{getMsg}=    Get Sheet Values    Messages
Login.Login by username and password    ${USER.${ENV}}    ${PASS.${ENV}}
```

The pop up always shows after finished login page and it cover some element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the preference of firefox `dom.webnotifications.enabled` to False. This will disappear the notification.

In robot you can do this by, creating a function

```
def create_profile(self):
    from selenium import webdriver
    fp=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled",False)
    fp.update_preferences()
    return fp.path
```

In .robot file add the following code:

```
${profile}=    create profile   
Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}    ff_profile_dir=${profile}
```

Comment: I have already created a function .py and then I input these script to robot file but how to input argument after create_profile keyword.

Comment: You can pass arguments by giving argument tag  ex->                               
Login
    [Arguments]    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    ${profile}=    create profile   
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}    ff_profile_dir=${profile}

Comment: Here Login is a keyword which has URL and BROWSER as arguments

Comment: I got error Keyword 'NotificationsBlock.Create Profile' expected 1 argument, got 0.  In your function have to put something after create profile.

Comment: In create_profile function, try removing self from it

Comment: I already removed self like this "def create_profile():" but I got error "NameError: global name 'false' is not defined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196367/discussion-between-sawitree-cha-and-say-w).